# Wheel collider is rotating cylinder, but cylinder does not roll

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

I'm making vehicle in Unity. I've followed this instruction http://docs.unity3d.com/ru/current/Manual/WheelColliderTutorial.html , but vehicle does not move. Wheels are rotating properly, but it does not move the car. I've tried to experiment with separate cylinder. I've added this

```
void Update () {
  GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().AddTorque (Vector3.right * 10);
}
```

It makes cylinder rotate such as circle collider did, and now cylinder rolls, as it should. But why it does not roll with circle collider?